# TextView set visibility gone if its empty

Tags: android, textview, android-view

Hi everyone why this code dose not work?
I have TextView get the value from sqlite database I want check if its empty hide TextView.

```
mTel1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_tel1);
    String ed_text = mTel1.getText().toString().trim();

    if(ed_text.length() == 0 || ed_text.equals("") || ed_text == null)
    {
        mTel1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }
    else
    {
        mTel1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

XML

```
  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_tel1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="#0066cc"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
```

Comment: Try this way if(mTel1.getText().toString().trim().length()>0)

Comment: Your condition needs to be changed as if(ed_text.length() == 0 || ed_text.equals("") || ed_text == null)
    {

     mTel1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        
    }
    else
    {
       mTel1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
    if(ed_text.length() == 0 || ed_text.equals(""))
    {
        mTel1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        mTel1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

Also, remember to always set visibility ="gone" in XML:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_tel1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textColor="#0066cc"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:textSize="18sp" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Did you try with:

```
if(ed_text.isEmpty())
{
     mTel1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);    
} else {
     mTel1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

This should do the trick.

You should also check if you TextView is populated with DB data when you call this.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
mTel1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_tel1);
    String ed_text = mTel1.getText().toString().trim();

    if(ed_text!=null && ed_text.length()> 0)
    {
        mTel1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }
    else
    {
        mTel1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your help, but its TextView invisible always

Answer (score 0):

Simple , Change your code like this,

```
if (ed_text == null || ed_text.isEmpty()) {
     mTel1.setVisibility(View.GONE);    
} else {
     mTel1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: `ed_text == null` should be the first check

Answer (score 0):

According to your question the answer is

```
if (tv.length() == 0) {
 tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

}

Or you can use

```
 if (TextUtils.isEmpty(tv.getText()){

   tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```